# How do I leverage my knowledge of Html/JS/CSS for iOs, Android, etc?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

Is it possible to create responsive, mobile-style apps without coding directly for iOS or Android with the same html/js/css stack that is used for major browsers?

Comment: look at the PhoneGap platform

Comment: There is an api from phonegap which allows you to create webapps in html/css/javascript and port them to any mobile os directly. It probably started from Adobe but now is a part of Apache Foundation and was started by Nitobi.

Comment: wow that was at a difference of 10 seconds..:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web Apps for cross platform mobile software development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221897/web-apps-for-cross-platform-mobile-software-development)

Comment: See also [HTML5 web app vs Native mobile apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548517/html5-web-app-vs-native-mobile-apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these books, they really helped me get started with developing for mobile using web technologies:

[Building Android Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449383268/)

[Building iPhone Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/)

As others have said you can make a web app styled for mobile.  There are some nice framworks to help you with styling and things like nice animated swipes etc. I would recommend looking at [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/).

For sencha there is a list of getting started resources in my answer to another stackoverflow question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967154/best-available-guide-to-sencha/3978285#3978285)

If you you want to make your web app native (and have access to features like the camera and accelerometer) I would recommend [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), but there are other frameworks already mentioned like Titanium.

Phonegap can be used along with Sencha Touch or jQueryMobile and has lots of resources to help get you started e.g. the [API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/index.html) docs and getting [started guide](http://phonegap.com/start) (check out the phonegap website for others)

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's called **Web App**.

You're probably goin to use some touch/mobile library like [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) or [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) to make the user interaction easier and fancy.

You don't need to code on C/Java to put out someting great for mobiles. ;)

Answer (score 0):

On top of that you can also use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) to create the complete "native" look and feel, without writing any code in Java/Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

@Jason if you have Good Knowledge in java scrip then i prefer to you to start with Appcelerator Titanium Click Here [Link For](http://developer.appcelerator.com/)   and [Link two](http://www.appcelerator.com/) This will good For Developing Application for iphone and android platform .There are lot Tutorial you can find for both android and iphone.